# django.core.exceptions.FieldError: Unknown field(s) (email) specified for Profile

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-rest-framework

I am trying to customize djoser's createuser end point. For that I have installed django custom user following this link https://github.com/jcugat/django-custom-user. Here is my models.py

```
from django.db import models
from custom_user.models import AbstractBaseUser


class Profile(AbstractBaseUser):
    account_address = models.CharField(max_length=30, blank=True)
```

and serializers.py

```
from djoser.serializers import UserCreateSerializer as BaseUserRegistrationSerializer


class UserRegistrationSerializer(BaseUserRegistrationSerializer):
    class Meta(BaseUserRegistrationSerializer.Meta):
        fields = ('url', 'id', 'email', 'first_name', 'account_address', 'password')
```

and in app.admin.py i have registered it in following way.

```
from django.contrib import admin
from custom_user.admin import UserAdmin
from .models import Profile


class MyCustomEmailUserAdmin(UserAdmin):
    """
    You can customize the interface of your model here.
    """
    pass


# Register your models here.
admin.site.register(Profile, UserAdmin)
```

but when I am trying to makemigrations i am running into following error. 
[image]

any clue what's wrong here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the looks of it, you seem to have the following in your settings:

`AUTH_USER_MODEL = "your_app.Profile"`

And for your profile model, you are inheriting from `AbstractBaseUser` which is actually from `from django.contrib.auth.models import AbstractBaseUser`.

I believe you meant to inherit from [AbstractEmailUser](https://github.com/jcugat/django-custom-user/blob/master/src/custom_user/models.py#L66). Thus, your "Profile" model would actually need be:

```
from custom_user.models import AbstractEmailUser


class Profile(AbstractEmailUser):
    account_address = models.CharField(max_length=30, blank=True)
```

Comment: I tried it alos , but when i try makemigration i am getting this "You are trying to add a non-nullable field 'password' to profile without a default; we can't do that (the database needs something to populate existing rows). "

Comment: It sounds like you have already created users/migrations under the original model. You would need to either alter the migration, or specify a default. If you are just starting your application, I suggest deleting existing migrations, clearing the database, and trying again.